# Find all audio files recursively and play them at random

Tags: php, html, audio, random, html5-audio

What would be a method that can find all audio files and play them at random.

I'm open to anything that works. I've tried many different methods I found online but they were all years old and didn't work.

My server has 2000+ songs and will grow.

Example of directories:

```
/var/html/Music/
  song1.mp3
  song2.mp3
/var/html/Music/Artist1/
  Song1.mp3
/var/html/Music/Artist1/Album 1/
  Song that has spaces and - (Parenthesis).mp3
```

Comment: `glob()` to get the files in an array, `shuffle()` to randomise the array, what ever to pay. We do expect you to show at least an attempt at writing the code yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer how I got what I needed:

First i ran a command on my linux server to find all files (-f) in my music directory and created an output with the link to every file "/Directory/For/Music/song.mp3"

```
find /Directory/For/Music/ -type f > /Any/Directory/You/Want/songs.index
```

Then:

```
<?php
/**Gets the list of files and returns a random line of the file**/
$f_contents = file("/var/www/html/scripts/songs.index");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
$data = $line;

/** print the contents of the names array */
echo($data);
?>
```